# how to make an inline keyboard in aiogram?

Tags: python, keyboard, inline, telegram-bot

the code calls the usual keyboard, besides, when you click on it, it does not transfer to the link

file 'main':

```
from config import BOT_TOKEN
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import keyboards as kb

bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#some code

@dp.message_handler(commands=['inline'])
async def show_items(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('It is buttons', reply_markup=kb.start_keyboard)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

file 'keyboards':

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

#some code

studyboi = InlineKeyboardButton('text', url='https://vk.com/feed')
start_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(studyboi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it. You use ReplyKeyboard - it is the normal button, that send the regular text in chat, and bot catch it. For link you need use inline button and inline keyboard.

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


#some code

studyboi = InlineKeyboardButton('text', url='https://vk.com/feed')
start_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(studyboi)
```